# How to fix in macro using if condition

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use this in VBA doesn't work gives error 
where a column contains like this

```
Aero 1.0
3/24/2019 2:38:08 PM
3/18/2019 2:30:40 AM
3/17/2019 4:06:46 PM
3/11/2019 12:03:20 AM
3/5/2019 9:11:53 AM
3/4/2019 1:20:56 AM
3/3/2019 3:58:11 PM
2/24/2019 3:43:24 PM
Affleck 1.0
3/24/2019 2:38:19 PM
3/18/2019 2:30:52 AM
3/17/2019 4:06:56 PM
3/11/2019 12:03:31 AM
```

in excel this works

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)="PM",RIGHT(A5,2)="AM"),F4,A5)
```

I need to put in macro.

this is for automation

```
IF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)="PM",RIGHT(A5,2)="AM"),F4,A5)
```

here is my coding

```
Sub folderMerge()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim oldfolderpath As String
    oldfolderpath = "C:\Users\dhason\Desktop\GPLM\master.xlsm"
    Dim fol As Folder
    Set fol = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\dhason\Desktop\GPLM\")
    Dim Postmeridian, Postmeridian, Platform As String
    Postmeridiem = "PM"
    Antemeridiem = "AM"
    For Each fil In fol.Files
    Workbooks.Open fil.Path
    For Each ws In Worksheets
         ws.Activate
         With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     End With
      Range("f4").Value = "Platform"
     Range("g4").Value = "Date"
     Range("h4").Value = "ODM"
     Range("i4").Value = "date value"
      Range("i5").Formula = "=datevalue(a5)"
     Range("f5").Formula = "=IF(OR(RIGHT((RANGE(A5,2).Value=PM), 
       (RIGHT(RANGE(A5,2)).VALUE=AM)),F4,A5)"
    Range("g5").Formula = "=LEFT(RC[-6],9)" ' second filling
        Range("g5", "g" & LastRow).Select
    Range("g5").Copy
    Range("g5:g" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        c = InStr(Range("A1").Value, " ") 'third filling
    Range("h5").Value = Left(Range("A1"), c)
    Range("A6").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select        
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Else
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 
 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        end If
        Next
Next
For Each wb In Workbooks
If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
wb.Close True
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is no useful error description. You need to explain what exactly you tried (include your code) and tell which error you get and in which line. Please read [ask] and how to build a [mcve] of your problem. Your question is a way to broad to answer if we don't know what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I am trying to use this formula =iF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)="PM",RIGHT(A5,2)="AM"),F4,A5) where in column a contains values like"Aero 1.0
3/24/2019 2:38:08 PM  etc" in vba macro im trying to write formula so that when i run macro the formula is taken by that particular cell and gives values here below is my entire coding

Comment: @reshmi22reshmi now you should also add into your question what is wrong with that code. We cannot know if you don't tell us. Which error do you get and in which line? We need an exact error description and much more information about what you are actually doing and where your code fails. • Also please read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and apply this technique to your code.

Comment: i get error on line Range("f5").Formula = "=IF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)="PM",RIGHT(A5,2)="AM"),F4,A5)" .it doesn't accept the PM or AM within quotes if i comment it other codes are working fine

Comment: Try to change it into `Range("f5").Formula = "=IF(OR(RIGHT((RANGE(A5,2).Value=""PM""), 
       (RIGHT(RANGE(A5,2)).VALUE=""AM"")),F4,A5)"` quotes need to be doubled in a string. • And please do your self a favour, even if the rest of your code works you really should read and apply
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Your code is a mess because of using `.Select`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - It says run time error object not defined

Comment: Ah of course you need to use the formula that already worked in the cells `IF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)=""PM"",RIGHT(A5,2)=""AM""),F4,A5)` •  Also note that if you declare `Dim Postmeridian, Postmeridian, Platform As String` only `Platform` is of type `String` and the other 2 variables are `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Postmeridian As String, Postmeridian As String, Platform As String` • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: OMG thank you so much i was breaking my head from 3 hours . this really worked IF(OR(RIGHT(A5,2)=""PM"",RIGHT(A5,2)=""AM""),F4,A5)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - can you tell me why do we use two double quotes?

Comment: @reshmi22reshmi Because this is how it works. See the documentation: [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions).

Comment: X-Y problem. Read the line as  date/time variable and then just put the relevant Excel data/time function in the formula to determine if it is am or pm. If you, in the future, intend to do this through VBA you could easily use the VBA date/time functions to do the same thing.